# NETCMN invalid driver designator

Tags: asp.net, oracle, iis

I have an Asp.Net project and I have configured the application in IIS under default pool sites. I am able to run the code via visual studio and when I refreshed the application in IIS and try to access it, it is showing error. I tried to run the same application in different server and there it is working fine. Below is the error:

```
ORA-06401: NETCMN: invalid driver designator
at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException.Check(OciErrorHandle errorHandle, Int32 rc)
at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection.OpenOnLocalTransaction(String userName, String password, String serverName, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean unicode, Boolean omitOracleConnectionName)
at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection..ctor(OracleConnectionString connectionOptions)
at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.Open()
at UPSFedExInvoice.UPS.Remittance.getUPSSubmitValue(String strQuery)
```

I tried to add missing reference DLL and updated webconfig file. But of no use

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/odp-dotnet-microsoft.html Read carefully. System.Data.OracleClient has been deprecated for long.

Comment: As Lex Li said,System.Data.OracleClient is a Microsoft .NET Framework data provider allowing you to connect to an Oracle database. But the provider is deprecated, it should not be used.
It's recommend that the usage of the [Oracle Data Provider for .NET/ODP.NET](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/dotnet/odp.html). More .NET Framework data providers and how they can be used for connecting to an Oracle database can be found in the [Oracle connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/) article.